# Recuperación de código de Aplicación

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de recuperar los archivos de código de una aplicación en Android, teniendo la aplicación instalada en el móvil.

He estado desarrollando una aplicación en mi portátil y éste se ha roto (fallo no tener una copia de seguridad). Por lo que he perdido todo el código del proyecto.

Pero si lo tengo instalado en el móvil, ¿es posible recuperarlo?

Comment: Muy difícil... para la  próxima, guarda versiones de tu app en Github y también ten sincronizada la carpeta de proyectos con una carpeta de Google Drive, de Dropbox u otro. Es como decir que pongas candado después de que te han robado, pero de los errores también se aprende.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gran error no respaldar tu proyecto.

Para obtener el .apk teniendo instalada la aplicación puedes usar el ADB que es como también se copia el .apk a tu dispositivo.

Primeramente obten la ruta del .apk, supongo que recuerdas el paquete de la aplicación:

```
adb shell pm path <paquete de aplicación>
```

Posteriormente, obteniendo la ruta puedes obtener el .apk mediante [ADB PULL](http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-pull) definiendo una ruta que puedas leer en tu dispositivo.

Por ejemplo si obtuviste como ruta :

```
/data/app/com.myapp.appperdida.apk
```

define una ruta en la cual copiarías tu .apk:

```
/storage/emulated/0//Android/data/
```

de esta forma obtendrías una copia del .apk instalado en tu dispositivo:

```
adb pull /data/app/com.myapp.appperdida.apk /storage/emulated/0//Android/data/
```

---

Teniendo el .apk puedes cambiar su extensión a .zip y obtener los recursos, .xml, imagenes, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto al código existen herramientas para obtenerlo a partir de los archivos `.dex`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para obtener el código, hablaré de deofuscación ya que comentas vas a obtener el código de tu propia aplicación.

Existen varías herramientas para esto como :

https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar
con http://jd.benow.ca/

o una online:
http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

recuerda,

> por ética no debemos robar el trabajo de otros desarrolladores.