# Recuperar código APK Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Lo que pasa es que por error se me borro el código de la una aplicación en Android, lo que me queda es el APK y el AndroidManifest, como puedo recuperar el código??

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.prj"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Sergio, como tienes el build.gradle y no el código? :-0  Por otro lado esto tal vez ya fue preguntado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59620/recuperaci%C3%B3n-de-c%C3%B3digo-de-aplicaci%C3%B3n/59640#59640

Comment: Si cuentas con el apk de tu aplicación la puedes decompilar en esta pagina: http://www.javadecompilers.com/ Sin embargo no te dará un proyecto compilable solamente las clases y los recursos de la app, te tocara reconstruir el proyecto a mano. es tardado pero si tu creaste el app podrás recuperar tu proyecto. saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió  javadecompilers.com, ya he recuperado la gran parte del proyecto.